ros2_control : How to set initial position of robot arm?
Hello my name is chanhui. my Ubuntu is 22.04 and ROS2 Humble, and my repository is https://github.com/chanhuirobot/rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm
looking my urdf file, in ros2_control tag, I set my joint initial_value with initial_positions.yaml file.

here is my robots initial_positions.yaml file

but looking my terminal... I found out something wrong.
chanhuirobot@chanhuirobot-ROG-Strix-G614JV:~$ ros2 launch rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm_moveit_config bringup.launch.py ros2_control_plugin:=real
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/chanhuirobot/.ros/log/2024-08-28-13-40-16-204065-chanhuirobot-ROG-Strix-G614JV-7832
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [7838]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [7840]
[INFO] [move_group-3]: process started with pid [7842]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [7844]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [7846]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [7848]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [7850]
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: update rate is 50 Hz
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[rviz2-4] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_base
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_hand_left
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_hand_right
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link5
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Received robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Initialize hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Number of joints= 7
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Configured
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Successful initialization of hardware 'RobotarmSystem'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: 'configure' hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'RobotarmSystem'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: 'activate' hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Starting ...please wait...
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: robotArm device opened 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint limits:
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint: revolute_1,  min,max:  -2.094395, 2.094395
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint: revolute_2,  min,max:  -2.094395, 2.094395
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint: revolute_3,  min,max:  -2.094395, 2.094395
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint: revolute_4,  min,max:  -2.094395, 2.094395
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint: revolute_5,  min,max:  -2.094395, 2.094395
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint: revolute_6,  min,max:  -2.094395, 2.094395
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Joint: slider_1,  min,max:  -0.026814, 0.018219
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: readJointPositions start
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loaded robot model in 0.000849362 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loading robot model 'rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm'...
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_1, pos= 313, -0.783304
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_2, pos= 825, 1.361357
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd  revolute_1: nan
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd          revolute_2: nan
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                  revolute_3: nan
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                          revolute_4: nan
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                  revolute_5: nan
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                          revolute_6: nan
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                                  slider_1: nan
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_3, pos= 561, 0.255516
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_4, pos= 505, 0.020944
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_5, pos= 720, 0.921534
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_6, pos= 492, -0.033510
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo slider_1, pos= 498, 0.001335
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: System Successfully started!
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'RobotarmSystem'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_1, pos= -2147483648, delta= -2147483648
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_1, pos= -2147483648, time 1500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_2, pos= -2147483648, delta= -2147483648
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_2, pos= -2147483648, time 1500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_3, pos= -2147483648, delta= -2147483648
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_3, pos= -2147483648, time 1500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_4, pos= -2147483648, delta= -2147483648
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_4, pos= -2147483648, time 1500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_5, pos= -2147483648, delta= -2147483648
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_5, pos= -2147483648, time 1500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_6, pos= -2147483648, delta= -2147483648
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_6, pos= -2147483648, time 1500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint slider_1, pos= -2147483648, delta= -2147483648
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo slider_1, pos= -2147483648, time 1500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd  revolute_1: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd          revolute_2: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                  revolute_3: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                          revolute_4: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                  revolute_5: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                          revolute_6: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                                  slider_1: 0.00155
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_1, pos= 500, delta= 500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_1, pos= 500, time 20
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_2, pos= 500, delta= 500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_2, pos= 500, time 20
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_3, pos= 500, delta= 500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_3, pos= 500, time 20
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_4, pos= 500, delta= 500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_4, pos= 500, time 20
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_5, pos= 500, delta= 500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_5, pos= 500, time 20
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint revolute_6, pos= 500, delta= 500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo revolute_6, pos= 500, time 20
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Update, joint slider_1, pos= 500, delta= 500
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Set servo slider_1, pos= 500, time 20
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: readJointPositions start
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_1, pos= 315, -0.774926
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_2, pos= 813, 1.311091
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_3, pos= 551, 0.213628
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_4, pos= 504, 0.016755
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_5, pos= 702, 0.846136
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_6, pos= 493, -0.029322
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo slider_1, pos= 496, 0.001119
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading controller 'hand_controller'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Loaded hand_controller
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Configuring controller 'hand_controller'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position].
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: readJointPositions start
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_1, pos= 425, -0.314159
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_2, pos= 707, 0.867080
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_3, pos= 495, -0.020944
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_4, pos= 501, 0.004189
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_5, pos= 585, 0.356047
[rviz2-4] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-4]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_6, pos= 498, -0.008378
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo slider_1, pos= 497, 0.001227
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Configured and activated hand_controller
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: readJointPositions start
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_1, pos= 500, 0.000000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_2, pos= 592, 0.385369
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_3, pos= 493, -0.029322
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_4, pos= 501, 0.004189
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_5, pos= 495, -0.020944
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_6, pos= 498, -0.008378
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo slider_1, pos= 497, 0.001227
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading controller 'arm_controller'
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Loaded arm_controller
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Configuring controller 'arm_controller'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position].
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Configured and activated arm_controller
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: readJointPositions start
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_1, pos= 500, 0.000000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_2, pos= 506, 0.025133
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_3, pos= 493, -0.029322
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_4, pos= 501, 0.004189
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 7850]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 7846]
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_5, pos= 495, -0.020944
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_6, pos= 498, -0.008378
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo slider_1, pos= 497, 0.001227
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: readJointPositions start
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_1, pos= 500, 0.000000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_2, pos= 506, 0.025133
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_3, pos= 493, -0.029322
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_4, pos= 501, 0.004189
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_5, pos= 495, -0.020944
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_6, pos= 498, -0.008378
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo slider_1, pos= 497, 0.001227
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 7848]
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: readJointPositions start
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_1, pos= 500, 0.000000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_2, pos= 506, 0.025133
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_3, pos= 493, -0.029322
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_4, pos= 501, 0.004189
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_5, pos= 495, -0.020944
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo revolute_6, pos= 498, -0.008378
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Read servo slider_1, pos= 497, 0.001227

looking this part, I exactly put slider_1 joint initial 0.0 but terminal shows it received 0.00155
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd  revolute_1: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd          revolute_2: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                  revolute_3: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                          revolute_4: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                  revolute_5: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                          revolute_6: 0.00000
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: New pos cmd                                                  slider_1: 0.00155

In fake(unconnected to robot) model, it is okay, but if I work this in real robot, this problem happens.
this is piece of my hardware interface. It sets its default position.. I found out, it follows this hardware interface's initial value (default value).


so, consequently, I want to know how to get initial position value from ros2_control and put it in hardware interface. Can you help me..?

Use : stod(info_.joints[i].state_interfaces[0].initial_value)
for i-th joint!

